# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: android, firebase, email, authentication

I am getting the following error:

> E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

And tried every other solution at StackOverflow. I am trying to email auth with firebase. Any help is appreciated.